# Wiremock Capture path param and return in the response body after "=" symbol only

Tags: json, api, wiremock, wiremock-standalone, wiremock-record

I am trying to create dynamic mocks using WireMock. My URL is like :

```
http://localhost:8080/manage/classids/query1=ns1/query2=id1
```

then I want output as

```
{ 
   "yourId":"id1"
}
```

I try do like this way

```
{
    "name": "Req_GET",
    "request": {
        "urlPathPattern": "/manage/classids/query1=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/query2=([a-zA-Z0-9]*)",
        "method": "GET"
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "jsonBody": {
            "yourId": "{{request.path.[3]}}"
        },
        "transformers": [
            "response-template"
        ],
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
}
```

but I am not able to split response after "=" it is coming whole after "/"

```
{ 
   "yourId":"query2=id1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the query parameter directly using WireMock's [request model](http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/#the-request-model)

```js
...
"yourId": "{{request.query.query1}}"
...
```